# How to handle the Crashes using Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I'm running robotium scripts to test the application. In one scenario after tapping on "Done" button application crashes, at this point my robotium script stopped working. How to handle this situation using robotium, is there any way that i will come know that application got crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Instrumentation tests live in the same process as your application, if you applications process crashes so do your tests. The way you can figure out your app crashed is that the instrument command process will end with an error code and then you will have to combine that with logcat to get the actual error that occurred.

Comment: Paul, can u let me know the necessary process to achieve this. I'm new to robotium.